# CakePHP return hasOne relationships within main result array

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a model class in CakePHP defined like this:

```
class Programme extends AppModel {
    public $hasOne = array(
        'ProgrammeLikes' => array(
        'className' => 'ProgrammeLikes',
        'fields' => array('likes'));
}
```

When retrieving my models from the database they are returned as an array with an array keyed to 'Programme' and a separate array keyed to 'ProgrammeLikes' (which contains the 'likes' value correctly). In order to reduce the changes necessary to  existing code I want the 'likes' value to be within the 'Programme' array.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [virtualFields](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html) here to get this thing to be done.

```
class Programme extends AppModel {
    public $hasOne = array(
        'ProgrammeLikes' => array(
        'className' => 'ProgrammeLikes',
        'fields' => array('likes')
    );

    public $virtualFields = array(
        'likes' => 'SELECT likes FROM programme_likes AS ProgrammeLikes WHERE ProgrammeLikes.id = Programme.programme_likes_id'
    ); 
    // Where programme_likes_id is the foriegnkey for Programme model

}
```

**Note:** I assumed `programme_likes` is your table name for `ProgrammeLikes` Model and `programme_likes_id` is the foriegnkey for 
`Programme` Model, so you can arrange the query in your own way that suits your requirement.

Comment: let me know if you've any query or concern

Comment: Thanks Anil. Works a treat.

Comment: glad to help you russell